# PHP Merge two array with duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array.

```
$ids = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110];
$users = [1,2,3,4,5];

for ($index = 0; $index < count($ids ); $index++) {
     echo $ids [$index] . $users [$index];
}
```

My Result;

```
100 - 1
101 - 2
102 - 3
103 - 4
104 - 5
```

I would like to merge it with duplicates ids.

```
100 - 1
101 - 2
102 - 3
103 - 4
104 - 5
105 - 1
106 - 2
107 - 3
108 - 4
109 - 5
110 - 1
```

Comment: sorry if my question is not correct, but I posted my current code with array and foreach.

Comment: Sounds like you want to loop over IDs, start to finish, and combine them with users, restarting that array once you reach the end. Is that correct? If so, can you explain where `5` is coming from?

Comment: yes! sorry I edited my array with 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your arrays are indeed this small, `array_shift` is a good tool. You can copy your array, pop an item off it continuously, and then re-copy the array as needed. The performance of `array_shift` gets worse as arrays grow large (as far as I've been told, but haven't personally witnessed).

```
$ids = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110];
$users = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Temporary copy of users
$user_ids = [];
foreach( $ids as $id ){
    
    // If our copy is empty, reload it
    if(!$user_ids){
        $user_ids = $users;
    }
    
    // Use array_shift() to grab and remove from the front
    echo sprintf('%1$d - %2$d', $id, array_shift($user_ids)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you `users` is indeed linear like that, you can also use modular arithmetic to repeat things:

```php
foreach( $ids as $idx => $id ){
    echo sprintf('%1$d - %2$d', $id, ($idx % 5) + 1 ), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Both demoed here: https://3v4l.org/LuRQj

Comment: Work perfect! $users array have max 10/20 users, ids array sometimes can have about 100/300 ids.

Comment: I use `array_shift` and similar with tens of thousands, although I don't use it on pages that demand high performance, and don't have any issues, so I think you'll be fine with just this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110];

$users = [1,2,3,4];

for ($index = 0; $index < count($ids); $index++) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {

        echo "<pre/>";

        echo $ids[$i] . "-".$users[$i];

    }

    $k=0;

    for ($j = $i; $j < $i + count($users); $j++) {

        echo "<pre/>";

        echo $ids[$j] . "-".$users[$k];

        $k++;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `<pre/>`? When I run this I get what appears to be a lot of extra items: https://3v4l.org/nlklb

Comment: you can remove it pre to show the items in separate lines

Comment: This solution, repeat ids a lot of times.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/MgqKK

Comment: The OP's sample output has 11 items, your sample output has 88 items, a lot of them duplicated. I'm also not seeing any items that start with 108, 109 or 110.